# What is the difference between ::std::string and std::string?

Tags: c++

what is the difference between `::std::string` and `std::string`
The former is global? But global for what?Is not namespace std global?
Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`::std::string` means `string` in namespace `std` in the global namespace. The leading `::` forces the lookup to start in the global namespace. Therefore `::std::string` always means the `string` type from the C++ standard library.

`std::string` means `string` in namespace `std`, where `std` will be looked up in the current scope. Therefore, if there is a class, namespace, or enum named `std`, name lookup might find that `std`.

```
#include <string>
namespace foo {
  namespace std {
    class string { ... };
    namespace bar {
      std::string s;    // means foo::std::string
      ::std::string s;  // means string from standard library
    }
  }
}
```

It is not necessary to use the leading `::` as long as you and your collaborators agree to not name anything `std`. It's just good style.